# Radial solution Poisson Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, poissons-equation

I am looking for a radial solution on $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
$$\Delta v=v''(r)+ {1 \over r}v'(r)=r-1$$

I already know that $v(r)=c_1 \ln(r)+c_2$ is a solution for $\Delta v=0$ and $v(1)=0$.

Setting $y=v'$ and $y'=v''$ we reach a linear equation of first degree:
$$y'= r-1-{y \over r}$$
How can this be continued?

Comment: Use an integrating factor $p(r) = \exp(\ln(r)) = r$ $$y' + r^{-1} y = r - 1 \implies ry' + y = r^{2} - r \implies (ry)' = r^{2} - r \implies ry = \int (r^{2} - r) \ dr$$